# Jquery ui with Jeditable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jeditable

I am trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
        submit    : 'OK',
        cancel : 'Cancel',
    });

    $('#cv_cd > input').autocomplete({
        source: 'location.php',
        minLength: 2

    });
});
</script>


<div class="edit" id="cv_cd">Type</div>
```

This code works properly with `<inputs />`, but with jeditable, no request is sent off when i type something.

After search the code with firebug,  jeditable also creates an `input` field, however apparently something like this didn't works   `$('#cv_cd > input').autocomplete({`

Any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.autocomplete()` is not *live*, so it only binds to elements that exist at the time of the call.

In your case, you'll want to use `live` or, preferably, `delegate` to accommodate the fact the `input` element will not exist until the user clicks on it. Knowing that the elements with autocomplete have `ui-autocomplete-input` class, you can do something like the following, in replace of the original `.autocomplete()`:

```
$("#cv_cd").delegate(".ui-autocomplete-input", "focus", function (event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'location.php',
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```