# Jeditable and Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jeditable

Hi I'm trying to put JEditable and JQuery UI Autocomplete together, so when I click a div, the div becomes editable, and the typed in content will have autocomplete feature, I've tried different solutions from other posts such as

1. [Jquery ui with Jeditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482583/jquery-ui-with-jeditable),
2. [How do you bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .on()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693758/how-do-you-bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-on),
3. [Bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551230/bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-live#new-answer?s=fec8973d279240e6953913da5787658d).

and finally come to some code look like this.

```
<div class="edit_school" id="edit_school_pending">ADD</div>

$(document).on(
    "focus", 
    ".edit_school:not(.ui-autocomplete-input)", 
    function(event) { 
         alert("Hey");
     $(this).autocomplete(
         {source: ["a","ab","aa","ac"]}
    );}
 );
```

JQuery version: jquery-1.9.1.js
JQuery UI version: code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

When click "ADD", the "ADD" is brought into a textbox, and an alert shows up, but typing "a" does not show any autocomplete. Please help and bear with the format if it does not turn out well. A lot thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out, for those who are also new to JEditable/Autocomplete, here's the working code:

```
    $(document).on(
        "focus", 
        ".edit_school", 
        function(event) { 
            alert(event.target);
            $(event.target).autocomplete(
                {source: ["a","ab","aa","ac"]}
            );
        }
    );

 <div class="edit_school" id="edit_school_pending">ADD</div>
```

Last post was not working due to call of "$(this).autocomplete()", here, $(this) refers to the div, not the input created by the JEditable. I was trying to set an id for the input created, but was not able to do that. But then figured out I have the access to the input element itself (event.target), and then call inputElement.autocomplete fixed the problem.

Comment: JEditable I was using: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable and JQuery UI Autocomplete I was using: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/